# Oracle remove rows from a query set based on sum

Tags: oracle, oracle-analytics

I have a table with data like below. INVENTORY_ITEM_ID is the unique id for the item, TYPE_QTY is the total quantity for the item in the unique age bucket (AGE_IN_DAYS) and RUNNING_TOTAL is a calculated column based on the TYPE_QTY on age buckets.

[image]

Each negative quantity requires to be removed from the final set of rows. For example, at the first occurrence of the negative quantity that is -508, the first rows that has running total that can satisfy the issuance of 508 should be identified and adjusted like below. All the rows above that row should be removed from the result set.

[image]

The RUNNING_TOTAL and TYPE_QTY columns are adjusted with the balance from (555-508) and the loop continues. The second issuance of -22 quantity happens against the first row as it has a running total 47 and final results for the given data should be like below

[image]

I've made a PL/SQL block that can do the job, however would prefer to achieve it using plain SQL. My current SQL skills are not enough to.

PL/SQL Block

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE

CURSOR INVDATA IS
SELECT tx.*
from OMSINVDT_TEMP tx
--where inventory_item_id = 35253
order by inventory_item_id,age_in_days desc;

CURSOR inline_data(p_item_id IN NUMBER) IS
SELECT inventory_item_id,
type_qty,
age_in_days,
SUM (type_qty) OVER ( PARTITION BY inventory_item_id ORDER BY age_in_days desc) RUNNING_TOTAL
FROM omsinvdata_temp
where inventory_item_id = p_item_id;

l_line_qty number;
l_last_age_period number := 0;

BEGIN

execute immediate 'truncate table omsinvdata_temp';

for i in invdata loop
--if the qty is greater than 0, add to the temp table
if i.type_qty > 0 then
        insert into omsinvdata_temp(
        inventory_item_id ,
        type_qty ,
        age_in_days ,
        running_total )
        values(i.inventory_item_id, i.type_qty, i.age_in_days, 0);
else
--if the quantity is negative
--open the cursor for the item from temporary table
--and find the row that can satisfy the negative quantity
--dbms_output.put_line('current quantity: '||i.type_qty);
for j in inline_data(i.inventory_item_id) loop
--dbms_output.put_line('Line Qty '||j.type_qty||' Running total: '||j.running_total||' To Issue: '||i.type_qty||' Bucket '||j.age_in_days);


if (abs(i.type_qty)>j.running_total) then
  --  dbms_output.put_line('Running total: '||j.running_total||' not sufficient to issue '||i.type_qty||' Bucket '||j.age_in_days);
    update omsinvdata_temp
    set type_qty =0,
    running_total =0
    where age_in_days = j.age_in_days
    and inventory_item_id = i.inventory_item_id;
    else
  --  dbms_output.put_line('Running total: '||j.running_total||' sufficient to issue '||i.type_qty||' Bucket '||j.age_in_days);
    update omsinvdata_temp
    set type_qty = j.running_total + i.type_qty,
    running_total = j.running_total + i.type_qty
    where age_in_days = j.age_in_days
    and inventory_item_id = i.inventory_item_id;
    exit;
 end if;

end loop;    
end if;
end loop;


commit;


END;
```

Create table script with shown data

```
CREATE TABLE "OMSINVDT_TEMP" ("INVENTORY_ITEM_ID" NUMBER, "TYPE_QTY" NUMBER, "AGE_IN_DAYS" NUMBER, "RUNNING_TOTAL" NUMBER)
REM INSERTING into OMSINVDT_TEMP
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into OMSINVDT_TEMP (INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,TYPE_QTY,AGE_IN_DAYS,RUNNING_TOTAL) values (35253,72,6,72);
Insert into OMSINVDT_TEMP (INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,TYPE_QTY,AGE_IN_DAYS,RUNNING_TOTAL) values (35253,384,5,456);
Insert into OMSINVDT_TEMP (INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,TYPE_QTY,AGE_IN_DAYS,RUNNING_TOTAL) values (35253,105,4,561);
Insert into OMSINVDT_TEMP (INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,TYPE_QTY,AGE_IN_DAYS,RUNNING_TOTAL) values (35253,-512,3,49);
Insert into OMSINVDT_TEMP (INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,TYPE_QTY,AGE_IN_DAYS,RUNNING_TOTAL) values (35253,-24,2,25);
Insert into OMSINVDT_TEMP (INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,TYPE_QTY,AGE_IN_DAYS,RUNNING_TOTAL) values (35253,134,1,159);
Insert into OMSINVDT_TEMP (INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,TYPE_QTY,AGE_IN_DAYS,RUNNING_TOTAL) values (266234,2,4,2);
Insert into OMSINVDT_TEMP (INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,TYPE_QTY,AGE_IN_DAYS,RUNNING_TOTAL) values (266234,1,3,3);
Insert into OMSINVDT_TEMP (INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,TYPE_QTY,AGE_IN_DAYS,RUNNING_TOTAL) values (266234,-1,2,2);
Insert into OMSINVDT_TEMP (INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,TYPE_QTY,AGE_IN_DAYS,RUNNING_TOTAL) values (266234,-2,1,0);
commit;
```

I've already asked this question to Oracle SQL/PLSQL community & failed to explain the construction logic.

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4480421/sql-match-quantity-and-pick-rows

Comment: I don't understand the logic here.

Comment: Can you explain which exact part of the logic?

Comment: The part I don't quite understand (not speaking for Tim B): Suppose the inputs are, in order, 30, 50, 80, -20 (with the corresponding running totals: 30, 80, 160, 140). Are you saying that now you must replace ALL FOUR rows, and instead just show one input of 140, with the running total 140? If that is so, then the problem actually simplifies to just finding the LAST negative number in the sequence, and replacing it and all the previous rows with a single row. However, I assume this is NOT the desired handling; but if it isn't, you didn't explain it correctly.

Comment: Also - are you looking to DELETE rows from the table and INSERT new rows? Or just write a **query** that produces the required output? (Or, equivalently, write a **view** that can compute the same output at any time in the future?)

Comment: @mathguy, consider the case 30,50,80,-20, 40,60. Against your example, I need to pick the last row with negative value (running total 140) and rest of the rows within the sequence. That will be rows with running total 140, 180,240.

Comment: OK, but then why do you need to present the problem as if it is a multi-step process? It can be done in the following simple steps: (1) Find the LAST negative input; (2) replace all the rows UP TO (and including) that row, using the running total up to that point; and keep all the remaining rows (which all have non-negative inputs). Is that it?

Comment: What happens if the first few rows with positive inputs are insufficient to satisfy a negative input? For example, can the sequence be 10, 40, 30, -500 (and then more positive rows)? And if something like that is possible, what is the required handling?

Comment: That can never occur. This data is against first in first out concept for Oracle inventory. So when there is -20 issue, the row above will have a positive number, either equal or more than the quantity that should be issued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, using only analytic functions and aggregation. You didn't explain the `AGE_IN_DAYS` column in the output - based on your example, I assume it represents the age of the most recent of the **positive** rows **preceding** the last negative row.

The `RUNNING_TOTAL` column shouldn't exist in the inputs, since it is calculated from the other data. Even though you have it in the table, I ignore it - I compute it directly. (I assume what you show is not your real starting data, but the point where you weren't able to continue with your solution.)

There is also a mismatch between the example you used and your `INSERT` statements. I used the `INSERT` statements as they are (with a different value for one of the rows); this explains why my output looks different from yours.

The main trick is in the `WITH` clause, in the `PREP` subquery. I assign a flag to the rows ***after*** the last "negative" row. Then in the main query I group by this flag, and in addition to that, *only when the flag is set*, by AGE_IN_DAYS. This way all the rows up to and including the last "negative" one are in one group, while the remaining positive rows are one row per group. (I assume that `AGE_IN_DAYS` is distinct for each `INVENTORY_ITEM_ID`; if it isn't, I could use something else, `ROWNUM` for example - but then the problem wouldn't be well defined anyway.)

So, here it is. Please review and let me know if you have any questions.

```
with prep as (
  select inventory_item_id, type_qty, age_in_days,
         case count(case when type_qty < 0 then 1 end) 
              over (partition by inventory_item_id order by age_in_days)
              when 0 then 'Y' end as past_last_negative
  from   omsinvdt_temp
)
select inventory_item_id, sum(type_qty) as type_qty,
       min(case when type_qty > 0 then age_in_days end) as age_in_days,
       sum(sum(type_qty)) over (partition by inventory_item_id
                                order by max(age_in_days)) as running_total
from   prep
group  by inventory_item_id,
          case past_last_negative when 'Y' then age_in_days end
order  by inventory_item_id, age_in_days desc
;

INVENTORY_ITEM_ID   TYPE_QTY AGE_IN_DAYS RUNNING_TOTAL
----------------- ---------- ----------- -------------
            35253         25           4           159
            35253        134           1           134
           266234          0           3             0
```

Comment: the result set is the exact one I was anticipating. Please allow me to apply it on a bigger set of data and get back to you. Thank you!

Comment: I have tested the query with a minor change (changed order by max(age_in_days)  to DESC) and the query you provided is generating the exact data that is produced by my PL/SQL block. I accepted your solution as answer. Thank you

Comment: I would like to address a minor concern that I realized at work today. If I have two more rows with negative values after a row with positive value. Would you like to help?

Comment: @RajeshThampi - sure. What is the concern? Do you think the query will not work? (I think it does - your sample data already included cases of two negative rows after a positive row). Or is your problem statement incorrect? Note that I asked you to confirm the statement before I wrote a solution.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for the delayed responses. Actually we were having troubles with VPN and our weekends are on Fridays and Saturdays. I will close this thread with your accepted solution and open a new thread as I believe the requirement has changed. Thank you 